# Pandas rolling conditional sum on time and group

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, rolling-computation, cumsum

I got an apparently hard task to do, in Python/Pandas.

I have a dataframe like this:

```
| DATETIME | PRODUCT | AMOUNT |
```

I need to produce the last column, with the cumulative sum of the (let's say sold product) amounts in the last 5 minutes, for each product (I have more than two products). See the following example:

```
| DATETIME              | PRODUCT | AMOUNT | CUM SUM        |
| 2020-01-01 17:10:00   | A       | 20     | 20 -> 20       |
| 2020-01-01 17:12:00   | B       | 30     | 30 -> 30       |
| 2020-01-01 17:13:00   | A       | 10     | 20+10 -> 30    |
| 2020-01-01 17:13:00   | A       | 15     | 20+10+15 -> 45 |
| 2020-01-01 17:16:00   | B       | 10     | 30+10 -> 40    |
| 2020-01-01 17:17:00   | A       | 15     | 10+15+15 -> 40 |
| 2020-01-01 17:20:00   | B       | 20     | 10+20 -> 30    |
| 2020-01-01 17:20:00   | B       | 10     | 10+20+10 -> 40 |
| 2020-01-01 17:25:00   | A       | 10     | 10 -> 10       |
```

Notice that couples (datetime, product) may not be unique, however I still have to keep an order based on the dataframe index.

I tried with:

1. Rolling function: but unfortunately I don't have a fixed window size, and I don't have unique couple (datetime, product) so I cannot use datetime as index and then use `.rolling('5 minutes')`.
2. `Groupby(product).cumsum()`: but I'm not able to restrict the sum to the only last few minutes.

Possibly, I need something smooth and not too bad on performance level, to be applied on a quite big df .

Do you have any hint?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you not do `resample` first (5min) and then rolling?

Comment: @DanailPetrov thank you, but I need a moving window, not fixed time steps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html), [`pd.DataFrame.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) by time window (5 minutes == '5T') and [`rolling.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.sum.html):

```
>>> df['CUM SUM'] = (df.set_index('DATETIME')
                       .groupby('PRODUCT')
                       .apply(lambda x: x.rolling('5T').sum()
                     ).values)

             DATETIME PRODUCT  AMOUNT  CUM SUM
0 2020-01-01 17:10:00       A      20     20.0
1 2020-01-01 17:12:00       B      30     30.0
2 2020-01-01 17:13:00       A      10     30.0
3 2020-01-01 17:13:00       A      15     45.0
4 2020-01-01 17:16:00       B      10     40.0
5 2020-01-01 17:17:00       A      15     40.0
6 2020-01-01 17:20:00       B      20     30.0
7 2020-01-01 17:20:00       B      10     40.0
8 2020-01-01 17:25:00       A      10     10.0
```

I am adding the exact steps, see if you can find any difference to your df:

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
DATETIME               PRODUCT  AMOUNT
2020-01-01 17:10:00    A        20
2020-01-01 17:12:00    B        30
2020-01-01 17:13:00    A        10
2020-01-01 17:13:00    A        15
2020-01-01 17:16:00    B        10
2020-01-01 17:17:00    A        15
2020-01-01 17:20:00    B        20
2020-01-01 17:20:00    B        10
2020-01-01 17:25:00    A        10"""), sep=r'\s\s+')
>>> df['DATETIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATETIME'])
>>> df

             DATETIME PRODUCT  AMOUNT
0 2020-01-01 17:10:00       A      20
1 2020-01-01 17:12:00       B      30
2 2020-01-01 17:13:00       A      10
3 2020-01-01 17:13:00       A      15
4 2020-01-01 17:16:00       B      10
5 2020-01-01 17:17:00       A      15
6 2020-01-01 17:20:00       B      20
7 2020-01-01 17:20:00       B      10
8 2020-01-01 17:25:00       A      10

>>> df['CUM SUM'] = (df.set_index('DATETIME')
                       .groupby('PRODUCT')
                       .apply(lambda x: x.rolling('5T').sum()
                     ).values)

>>> df

             DATETIME PRODUCT  AMOUNT  CUM SUM
0 2020-01-01 17:10:00       A      20     20.0
1 2020-01-01 17:12:00       B      30     30.0
2 2020-01-01 17:13:00       A      10     30.0
3 2020-01-01 17:13:00       A      15     45.0
4 2020-01-01 17:16:00       B      10     40.0
5 2020-01-01 17:17:00       A      15     40.0
6 2020-01-01 17:20:00       B      20     30.0
7 2020-01-01 17:20:00       B      10     40.0
8 2020-01-01 17:25:00       A      10     10.0
```

I noticed I missed the closing parenthesis after values, fixed.

**EDIT**

This works for `pandas 1.2.0`, for `pandas 1.0.5':

```
>>> df['CUM SUM'] = (df.set_index('DATETIME')
                       .groupby('AMOUNT')
                       .apply(lambda x: x.rolling('5T').sum().reset_index(drop=True))
                       .values)
```

Comment: I guess this is very close to what I need, but arises 'ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis'

Comment: I guess in your original dataframe your index is already set as `DATETIME`, in that case you do not need the `.values` part at the end, nor do you need the `.set_index('DATETIME')` part.

Comment: No, `DATETIME` is just a column. I tried also with my example dataframe and it arises the same error (inferring a bracket before `.values`)

Comment: Did you try running only the right hand side? I mean without assigning the value into the dataframe? If so, does that give an error as well?

Comment: I have pasted the exact steps I performed to get the result, please let me know what I am missing.

Comment: they're exactly the same code! I'm using `pd.__version__` -> `'1.0.5'`

Comment: I see, I am using `1.2.0`. Let me check. Though I thought it would work with any pandas version >= 1.

Comment: I'm updating my conda environment too. Anyway, if it won't help, I think I could do like this: 
`df.groupby('PRODUCT').apply(lambda x: 
    x.set_index('DATETIME').rolling('5T').sum()
)`
and then join somehow

Comment: Edited for `1.0.5`.

Comment: The last (for `1.0.5`) does not match correctly the rows, since the right hand side is grouped by `PRODUCT` and after resetting indexes it remains grouped. ANYWAY, after updating to `1.2.0` the first you proposed seems to finally work! THANK YOU!